# Format outlook email with Python win32 and allow for a class to be used within the HTMLbody

Tags: python, outlook, html-email, win32com, office-automation

I am trying to make a basic outlook email template for one of my tasks at work. The goal is to be able to run a script and provide a number to the program such that I can generate repetitive blocks of code for releasing materials in our warehouse. I have figured out how to draft the email (need manual inputs so using mail.save to make a draft), but I am struggling to come up with a way to populate x blocks of code for the name/tracking/item/lot/containers potion of the HTML body (used // to denote the repetitive block). I think I will probably need to remove the r""" """ bit and use quotes so that a function can be used in the middle of the HTMLbody, but I'm not sure. Here is the current code I have:

```
import win32com.client as win32
import os

outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)

# SEND TO

mail.To = 'Email here'

# SUBJECT

mail.Subject = 'Subject here'

# MESSAGE BODY

mail.HTMLBody = r"""
    The following stuff is ready: <br><br>

    <b>Name</b><br>          //This is the block of code I want to repeat X times.
    Tracking #/ WO #: <br>
    Item #: <br>
    Lot #: <br>
    X containers <br><br>    //This is the end of the repeatable block

    Best regards, <br><br>

    <p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt"><b>My Name</b><br>
    Title<br>
    Company<br>
    D: phone number here<br>
    fakeEmail@somedomain.com<br>
    www.fakesite.com<br></p>

"""

mail.Save()
```

I originally tried to do something like this with the body portion, which I imagine is closer to what I will need:

```
mail.HTMLBody = (
"text here"
class call here for repetitive block
"text here to finish signature"
)
```

Would this approach work better for my goal?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to build an HTML string based on the data from an external source. The [MailItem.HTMLBody](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.htmlbody) property returns or sets a string representing the HTML body of the specified item. The `HTMLBody` property should be an HTML syntax string, that means the string should represent a well formed HTML document.